# Difference between Python 3.x and Python 2.x in while loop

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, while-loop

I have this piece of code, which I had written a few weeks ago. Initially I wrote it for Python 2.7 and it works very well, but I decided some time ago to just abandon it, and move to Python 3.7. Can anyone explain me why this `while` loop is infnite and doesn't want to fullfill those conditions?

In Python 2.7 this code allows me to browse between my files of data, and those amateurs tricks in my code allows me to handle obstackles such as changing hour after 60 minutes or date after 24 hours. Still have no idea how to convert it to Python 3.

```
# Input variables
h = "Arctic"
u = 'Denver'
p = 'Patagonia'

Station = input('Enter a station name (Arctic = h, Denver = u, Patagonia = p): ')
Date = input('Enter date time (yyyymmdd): ')
Date_end = input('Enter end date time (yyyymmdd): ')
Start_time_hours = int(input('Enter start time (hh): '))
Start_time_minutes = int(input('Enter start time (mm): '))
End_time_hours = int(input('Enter end time (hh): '))
End_time_minutes = int(input('Enter end time (mm): '))
Save_Print_SavPrin = input('Press s = Save, p = Plot: ')


while Start_time_hours == Start_time_hours and Start_time_minutes == Start_time_minutes and Date == Date:
    Start_time_hours += (Start_time_minutes / 60)
    Start_time_minutes %= 60
    str(Start_time_minutes)
    str(Start_time_hours)
    str(End_time_minutes)
    str(End_time_hours)
    Start_time_hours_format = '{:02}'.format(Start_time_hours)
    Start_time_minutes_format = '{:02}'.format(Start_time_minutes)
    End_time_hours_format = '{:02}'.format(End_time_hours)
    End_time_minutes_format = '{:02}'.format(End_time_minutes)
    int(Start_time_minutes)
    Start_time_minutes += 5
    if Save_Print_SavPrin == "p":
        print("Showing figures...")
        print ("Succesful!")
        if Start_time_hours_format == End_time_hours_format and Start_time_minutes_format == End_time_minutes_format and Date == Date_end:
            print (Start_time_hours_format, Start_time_minutes_format, End_time_hours_format, End_time_minutes_format)
            break
```

Comment: `Start_time_hours += (Start_time_minutes / 60)` should be rewritten as `Start_time_hours += (Start_time_minutes // 60)` to keep up with integer division.

Comment: `str(Start_time_minutes)` alone does nothing useful. neither does `int(Start_time_minutes)`

Comment: `while Start_time_hours == Start_time_hours and Start_time_minutes == Start_time_minutes and Date == Date:` is always true. you're comparing the variable to themselves....

Comment: the issue is probably floating point division here `Start_time_hours += (Start_time_minutes / 60)` which changes the representation as string and the break is never called. But your code needs a lot of simplifying.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yeah I know, but to be honest that was the only thing I was able to think about, maybe you have better idea to change this condition, I'd be glad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your loop condition is an infinite loop, because you're comparing variables to ... themselves. So you can replace by `while True:` (valable for both python versions)

Now the problematic code is this:

```
Start_time_hours += (Start_time_minutes / 60)
```

in python 3, `/ 60` performs floating point division, even between integer operands. The result is that now `Start_time_hours` is a float, and can never be equal to `End_time_hours`, which is an integer (the `if Start_time_hours_format == End_time_hours_format` test always fails, specially because you're converting both to string).

The fix (works for both versions) is to force integer division:

```
Start_time_hours += (Start_time_minutes // 60)
```

Aside, doing `str(something)` alone on a line isn't going to turn that `something` into a string unless you assign it back to `something`. You can remove all those statements, as they're useless anyway.